# Paypal auto return is not redirecting after successful payment

Tags: php, paypal, returnurl

I have been struggling for the past few days trying to get Paypal to redirect to my website after a successful payment. Instead, it shows this "Thank you for your order" and asks me to click on a link to return to the merchant page, from which it takes 10 seconds to redirect. I thought that the auto return feature was supposed to skip the entire "Thank you for your order" page.

The account in question has auto-return enabled and it has PDT enabled.

Here's the code I have, and to be honest, I do not understand why it does not return automatically after the successful payment is processed.

```
<form id="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="#####@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?= "Modele ".$_POST['model']." ".$_POST['shp']." de couleur: ".$_POST['clr'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?= $_POST['amount_with_tax'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://######.com/success.php?id=<?= $con->insert_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://######.com/cancel.php?id=<?= $con->insert_id ?>">
</form>
```

I realize this a sandbox url, but it should work either way, no?

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks.

PS: I have a javascript line that submits the form automatically on page load.

Comment: Auto return feature will not skip the "Thank you for your order" page.It takes few second before re-directing to return page.
btw, if the transaction is made via credit/debit card, auto return will not work.

Comment: In that case, what is the feature I am looking for, if it's not auto-return? I've seen many sites that use PayPal for their transactions go to their hosted success page when a transaction is successfully completed, skipping the thanks for your order page.

Comment: Those other sites have integrated different PayPal payments products, probably Express Checkout, rather than Website Payments Standard (which is what you show above, with _xclick buttons). As techycommerce said, you are getting the correct (and only) behavior supported by WPS. See also this question's accepted answer for a discussion of the difference in products and PayPal's recommendations for ensuring you get customer information with WPS (basically, also implement IPN): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484470/how-can-i-skip-the-paypal-payment-confirmation-page-altogether

Comment: By the way: PayPal's reasoning for this is that with WPS the payment is made on PayPal's site when the user hits the Pay button. Paypal wants to make sure the user sees some confirmation of their action. If PayPal immediatelys redirects you may, or may not, always correctly provide confirmation (merchant integrations are not always... excellent :). So they make sure to inform the user that they have a payment, then turn control back over to the merchant. With API integrations payment usually doesn't happen until the customer has returned to the merchant's site, so PP has to trust the merchant.

Comment: Consider that you can create a website payments standard button without even having a PayPal account. PayPal doesn't want it to be that simple to accidentally (or maliciously) leave buyers hanging or misinformed about whether they have made a payment.

Comment: I have IPN enabled, messages "on". So instead of using the return parameter, I should use the notify_url parameter and implement IPN on the thank you page. Is that a correct assessment?